# Oracle client can't connect to remote server

Tags: oracle

On win7 64 bit, PL/SQL Developer client login message: "Initailization error, SQL*Net not properly installed, OracleHomeKey: ;OracleHomeDir:".

The server is a remote server, I only have a sql client, because I can access database via java code, so thought that the tnslistener has been started on that server, am I right?

Comment: you need to check the installation , if SQL*Net is installed , also check if tnslistener is started , you can check the same via lsnrctl

Comment: get oracle client re-installed on your system

Comment: if you have sql plus installed, try tnsping dbname to confirm you can make a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The listener is on the server, if you can connect to the server via java, the listener is running.  So not a listener problem.  The error states that your client is not properly installed.  The PL/SQL developer software it trying to use sqlnet via the oracle client to access the oracle database.  The sqlnet driver is reporting that your installation is either not configured or is not properly installed.  What oracle client is installed on your win7 box?  Did you install the instant client from oracle 10g/11?  Did you install the full client for oracle 10g/11?  Uninstall the bad install client, reinstall and configure/run the client software to test sqlnet.

Comment: You thought line is clear enought, I have resolved this issue, which really like you said, thank you very much.